# create drowdownlist persons(name,ID) from database MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have problem creating dropdosnlist using EF in my controller I have to get list of person with names and IDs to bind it dropdosnlist just want what is the best way to dropdosnlist from controller code ?

```
    person model

           using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;

            public partial class Person
            {
                public Person()
                {
                    this.Addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
                }

                public int PersonID { get; set; }
                public string FirstName { get; set; }
                public string LastName { get; set; }
                public string MiddleName { get; set; }
                public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
                public string Gender { get; set; }

                public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
            }

    public class AddressController : Controller
        {

            private readonly CustomersDBEntities context = new CustomersDBEntities();

            ///get list of persones
            /// 
            public List<Person> GetPersonsList()
            {
                return (from c in context.Persons
                        select c).ToList();
            }

            //
            // GET: /Address/

            public ActionResult Index()
            {


                var model = GetPersonsList().Select(x =>new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = x.PersonID.ToString(),
                    Text = x.FirstName,
                    Selected = true | false
                }).ToList();

                return View(model);
            }

            // 
            // GET: /Address/Welcome/ 

            public string Welcome()
            {
                return "This is the Welcome action method...";
            }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Address address)
        {
            //Loop through the request.forms

            var Addesslist = new List<Address>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= Request.Form.Count; i++)
            {
                var street = Request.Form["street_0" + i + ""];
                var city = Request.Form["city_0" + i + ""];
                var postalCode = Request.Form["postalCode_0" + i + ""];
                var province = Request.Form["province_0" + i + ""];
                var personID = 1;
                if (street != null && city != null && postalCode != null && province != null)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        context.Addresses.Add(new Address
                        {
                            Street = street,
                            City = city,
                            Province = province,
                            PostalCode = postalCode,
                            PersonID = personID
                        });
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (Exception exc)
                    {

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }



Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'personList' does not exist in the current context
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Address", FormMethod.Post))
{

   @Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.Person,personList);



    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="address_table" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Street</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Province</th>
                        <th>PostalCode</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Text1" type="text" name="street_01" maxlength="255" required class="street" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Text2" type="text" name="city_01" maxlength="255" required class="city" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Text3" type="text" name="province_01" maxlength="255" required class="province" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Text4" type="text" name="postalCode_01" maxlength="7" required class="postalCode" /></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Add Row" id="add_AdressRow" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" />

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>

}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

update error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'MVC.Models.Address' does not contain a definition for 'Persons' and no extension method 'Persons' accepting a first argument of type 'MVC.Models.Address' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a model for building the dropdown (or use the one you have) and pass to view?

```
public class PersonModel
{
  public int SelectedId {get;set;}
  public List<Person> Persons {get; set;}
}
```

Call this method and pass the model to your view

```
public List<Person> GetPersonsList()
    {
        return (from c in context.Persons
            select c).ToList();
    }

    //
    // GET: /Address/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new PersonModel{ Persons = GetPersonsList()};
        return View(model);
    }
```

And then in your view build the list:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedId, new SelectList(Model.Persons, "PersonId", "FirstName"))
```

Comment: If you are using EF why remake the datamodel? Why not just use a list of the already defined `Persons` and add the other bits you need to your model?

Comment: can you explane more ??

Comment: EF will automatically create a datamodel for each entity in your database that you have built.  You should just be able to query and toList() the persons table and map it to a `List<Person>`.  Try working with what I posted above, when ever i need to make a simple drop down from the database I simply build a list from the DB directly and not define a custom model.

Comment: Try just doing `var model = GetPersonsList()` you are calling `toList()` on a method that is already returning a list.

Comment: Try using a less complex model like the one I wrote above to get the dropdown to work initially and scale up the complexity from there.  Your code above does not look any different.